# Using layer cake representation in proving Hardy-Littlewood-Sobolev inequality

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis, lp-spaces

[image]

This is Theorem 4.3 page 106 in "Analysis" of Lieb and Loss.

There is a step in the proof that I cannot understand:
(I am writing in a less elegant way for the sake of clarity)
$$\int_{\mathbb{R}^{n}}\int_{\mathbb{R}^{n}}\chi_{\{x:f(x)>a\}}{(x)}\chi_{\{x:h(x)>b\}}{(y)}\chi_{\{x:|x|<c\}}{(x-y)}\,dxdy$$
$$\leq 
\frac{\int_{\mathbb{R}^{n}}\chi_{\{x:f(x)>a\}}{(x)}dx\,\int_{\mathbb{R}^{n}}\chi_{\{x:h(x)>b\}}{(x)}\,dx\,
C_n\, c^n}{\max\{\int_{\mathbb{R}^{n}}\chi_{\{x:f(x)>a\}}{(x)}dx,\,\int_{\mathbb{R}^{n}}\chi_{\{x:h(x)>b\}}{(x)}\,dx,\,
C_n\, c^n\}}
$$
It says in the book, the integrals in $x,y$ can be estimated from above by replacing one of the characteristic functions by 1.

My question is: why can we bound

$$\int_{\mathbb{R}^{n}} \int_{\mathbb{R}^{n}} f(x)g(y) \chi_{\{x:|x|<R\}}{(x-y)}\, dx\,dy=
\int_{|x-y|<R}f(x)g(y) \, dx\,dy$$
by
$$
\frac{\int_{\mathbb{R}^{n}} f(x)dx\,\int_{\mathbb{R}^{n}} g(x)dx\; |B_{R}(o)|}{\max\{\int_{\mathbb{R}^{n}} f(x)dx,\,\int_{\mathbb{R}^{n}} g(x)dx,\; |B_{R}(o)|\}
}$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use $0 \le f(x),g(y) \le 1$.

We always have $\int_{|x-y|<R} f(x)g(y)dxdy \le \int_{(\mathbb{R}^n)^2} f(x)g(y)dxdy = \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} f(x)dx\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} g(y)dy$, so we're done if the maximum is $|B_R(0)|$. We also have $\int_{|x-y| < R} f(x)g(y)dxdy \le \int_{|x-y|<R} g(y)dxdy = |B_R(0)|\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}g(y)dy$. Same thing with $f$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I thought I get the first line, but I don't. What can we do to assume that $0\leq f,g\leq 1$ without losing generality ?

Comment: The step in the proof you said you didn't understand had to do with indicator functions, which are between $0$ and $1$.

Comment: yes. I kind of forgot the setting for a moment.  Thanks again.